# Access scope binding with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angular-ui-router

I have a login route and page in my AngularJS application with ui-router.
In my login.html partial loaded with ui-view I have a login page with the username and password inputs bound to credentials.username and credentials.password. If I want to access those credentials in my LoginCtrl I get 'username of undefined' error.

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
       url: '/login',
       templateUrl: '/partials/login.html',
       controller: 'loginCtrl'
    });
});
```

loginCtrl.js:

```
myApp.controller('loginCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.credentials.username = 'Test';
});
```

In my partials/login.html I have a simple login form with 2 inputs with:

```
<input type='text' name='username' ng-model='credentials.username' placeholder='Username...' autoFocus>
<input type='password' name='password' ng-model='credentials.password' placeholder='Password...'>
```

Where autoFocus is a custom directive for autofocussing the username field. The form is shown fine, but I still can't access my bindings in my controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your getting the "username of undefined" error is because `$scope.credentials` is undefined, and you are trying to assign a value to `$scope.credentials.username`.

The way to make this work is to define it first:

```
$scope.credentials = {};
$scope.credentials.username = "someDefaultUsername";
```

The bindings would work just fine with a dot - in fact, it is the recommended way due to common errors with how prototypical scope inheritance (but that is beside the point):

```
<input ng-model="credentials.password" type="password">
```

**Off-topic:** a directive with a camel case, like `autoFocus`, needs to be denormalized into a hyphenated name in HTML, otherwise it would not be found by Angular's compiler.

```
<input ng-model="credentials.username" auto-focus>
```